# Moving view using touch events

Tags: java, android, view

I want to make an application with sliding navigation, i.e. user can move views horizontally, sliding them in or out.
Currently I have implemented my custom `ViewGroup` with my layout and measurement settings (overridden onLayout and onMeasure).
Also I have implemented `OnTouchListener` calculating difX from starting event point to end point.

But I dont know how to apply this difX to my views to change their position.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [`setTranslationX()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationX%28float%29) method to change view's position according to delta X value. You can do it in `onTouchEvent()`. Do not forget to call `invalidate()` to force re-draw.